# How to print column number of last character of line in file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to print the column number of last character of line. I have a file. So I want to print the column number of last character of line which has highest number in file.

Thanks.

Comment: So... the length (number of characters) of the longest line?

Comment: Try wc --max-line-length FILE

Comment: Yes longest line.  wc --max-line-length FILE works